# return a list-object from a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, collections

How do i return all the List entries that are within the Dictionary

```
public class Meter
{
    public string MeterID { get; set; }
    public List<Data> data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public int Signal { get; set; }
}
```

Meter is a Dictionary string, Meter
I have tried with this

```
private static Dictionary<string, Meter> meters = new Dictionary<string, Meter>();
public static List<Meter> GetDataList()
{
    return meters.Where(g => g.Key.Equals(Data)).Select(g => g.Value).ToList();
}
```

Comment: What is the meters? a collection of Meter classes?

Comment: Is the dictionary `Dictionary<string, Meter>` or `Dictionary<Data, Meter>`? It's not clear.

Comment: what exactly you need to select from meters? a combined list of all data-s (as single `List<Data>`)?

Comment: meters is a collection of Meter and Dictionary<string, Meter> and a sigle list would be prefered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select single list of Data for all meters:

```
public static List<Data> GetDataList()
{
    return meters.Values.SelectMany(m => m.data).ToList();
}
```